# React js error "Unexcepted token" while accessing via VPN(bdirect)

Tags: reactjs, vpn

We are developing an application in React and will be hosted in IIS, after hosting application runs fine when we try to access through server name but when i am trying to access through VPN(Bdirect) we are getting js error "Unexcepted token'!=='", attach screen shot. We have developed the basic application using create-react-app.

[image: using server name]

[image: using VPN]